# Keras custom sequence gets mysterious out-of-bound error during training

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've written a custom Keras sequence to feed into the model variably sized images, that is, images with the same dimension (540 x 360 or 360 x 540) but rotated by different degrees. In each batch all images have the same shape, but different batches may have different shapes. My method to do this is to first iterate through all images rotated by -30 degrees, and then -28... Here's the code:

```py
class RotatedImageSequence(keras.utils.Sequence):
    """
    Custom image data sequence:
    Within the same batch, the images are of the same shape.
    Different batches may have different shapes.
    """

    def __init__(self, score_df: 'pd.DataFrame', long_pics_list: 'list[str]', wide_pics_list: 'list[str]', batch_size: 'int') -> None:
        self.score_df = score_df
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.long_pics_list = long_pics_list
        self.wide_pics_list = wide_pics_list

        self.processing_long_pics = True
        
        self.current_angle = -30
        self.current_pic_index = 0

    def __len__(self) -> 'int':
        assert len(self.score_df) % self.batch_size == 0
        return len(self.score_df) // self.batch_size
    
    def __getitem__(self, index: 'int') -> 'tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]':
        if self.processing_long_pics:
            batch_pics_names = self.long_pics_list[self.current_pic_index: self.current_pic_index + self.batch_size]
            self.current_pic_index += self.batch_size
        else:
            batch_pics_names = self.wide_pics_list[self.current_pic_index: self.current_pic_index + self.batch_size]
            self.current_pic_index += self.batch_size
        
        batch_pics = np.array([cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_dir, pic_name, '%+d.jpg' % self.current_angle)) for pic_name in batch_pics_names], dtype=np.uint8)
        batch_scores = np.array([self.score_df.loc[self.score_df['filename'] == '%s/%+d' % (pic_name, self.current_angle), 'score'].values[0] for pic_name in batch_pics_names], dtype=np.float32)

        if self.processing_long_pics:
            if self.current_pic_index >= len(self.long_pics_list):
                self.processing_long_pics = False
                self.current_pic_index = 0
        else:
            if self.current_pic_index >= len(self.wide_pics_list):
                self.processing_long_pics = True
                self.current_pic_index = 0
                self.current_angle += 2
        return batch_pics, batch_scores / 60

    def on_epoch_end(self) -> None:
        self.current_angle_index = 0
        self.current_pic_index = 0

        np.random.shuffle(self.long_pics_list)
        np.random.shuffle(self.wide_pics_list)

        # report time when an epoch ends
        print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time())))
```

I first tried a dry-run of the training sequence: I just iterated through the sequence with a dummy for-loop, and no exception was raised. But when I called model.fit() with the following code, something went wrong:

```py
hist = model.fit(train_set,
                 validation_data=val_set,
                 batch_size=1,
                 epochs=50,
                 verbose=2,
                 shuffle=False,
                 callbacks=[keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='saved-model-{epoch:03d}-{val_loss:.4f}-{val_mae_unscaled:.4f}-{loss:.4f}-{mae_unscaled:.4f}',
                            save_best_only=False,
                            save_freq='epoch'),
                            keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)])
```

I got an error, saying `[ WARN:0@13784.807] global loadsave.cpp:244 findDecoder imread_('[my workspace path]/Dataset/BlurredRotation/1528_1/+32.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity` (1528_1 is the first of the `long_pics`).

Originally, in each epoch I used a randomly permuted sequence of angles (a 31-element array of the angles -30, -28, ..., 28, 30), but I still got roughly the same error: instead of failing to load the image from the disk, an index-out-of-bound exception was thrown: `IndexError: index 31 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 31`.

Comment: I have changed my code multiple times and still get similar errors. Then I discovered that it could actually have been caused by a bug in Keras: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/17946#issuecomment-1515862254